# loading contents of PHP file in MVC architecture

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

So I'm using Codeigniter and I was wondering how I can load in the contents of my view directly into a calling JS file.

I have a view called "form_layout" which contains PHP code to populate form fields.

```
    $('#wizard').smartWizard
    ({contentURL:'views/form_layout.php?action=1',
transitionEffect:'slideleft',onFinish:onFinishCallback});
```

but when I do that I get a server 500 error.

Do i have to route through the controller like?

```
<?php
class Form_manager extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('form_template');
    }
}
?>
```

and do `contentURL:Form_manager/index`?

Comment: $view = $this->load->view('form_template');
echo $view;

tried that?

Comment: Hm I do not think that is the proper way to handle it. It seems CI does not allow me to remotely access my views unless it's routed through a controller which makes sense, but I need to load in the contents of a view into this JS file.

Comment: Why would you need to load a view result into a js file? Use the view file for that.

Comment: All files within the `application` folder are protected from being directly accessed for obvious security reasons. Reason why all calls are proxied through the `index.php` file in main directory. You would need to use a controller to access the content. Also on a side note you can do this `$string = $this->load->view('my_view_file', '', TRUE);` then pass `$string` to the current view and echo it into the page depending on if it was needed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 var SITEURL = 'yourdomainname'; //like www.mysite.com

 $('#wizard').smartWizard({
   contentURL: SITEURL + '/Form_manager/index/action/1',
   transitionEffect:'slideleft',onFinish:onFinishCallback
 });



 <?php
 class Form_manager extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($action )
   {
     echo  $this->load->view('form_template','',true);
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Oh god. This is wrong on so many levels. 1. Why do you declare `SITEURL` when CodeIgniter provides you with `site_url()`. If your site url changes, you now have to change it at multiple places. 2. Why does `index` need an `action` argument when it isn't being used. 3. Your content URL needs nothing after `form_manager`. These is no need for `/index/action/1`.

Comment: @xbonez:  1. site_url() is php function you can't use it in js files.

2. You can declare SITEURL in once, and use it throughout the site.
3.If you are passing action parameter as 1 in content URL then you need index in in contentURL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to route through a controller. CodeIgniter does not allow you to short-circuit routes to views directly (unlike Laravel). So, you will have to set up the controller as you show and change the url in your ajax call to `site_url('form_manager')`. You don't need to specify `/index` since that is the default function that CI calls when none is specified in the URL.

Comment: If index function has parameter then you need to specify /index.

Comment: You can see it, in his js code 
contentURL:'views/form_layout.php?action=1'